# 16 million goroutines - "GC assist wait"

Tags: go, garbage-collection, goroutine, mandelbrot

I'm running a go program that computes the mandelbrot set. A gouroutine is started for every pixel to compute convergence. The program runs fine for `pixelLengthx = 1000`, `pixelLengthy = 1000`.
If I run the same code for `pixelLengthx = 4000`, `pixelLengthy = 4000`, the program starts printing this after a few dozen seconds:

```
goroutine 650935 [GC assist wait]:
main.converges(0xa2, 0xb6e, 0xc04200c680)
.../fractals/fractals.go:41 +0x17e
created by main.main
.../fractals/fractals.go:52 +0x2af
```

The program does not terminate and just continues printing.

```
package main

import (
    "image"
    "image/color"
    "image/draw"
    "image/png"
    "log"
    "math/cmplx"
    "os"
    "sync"
)

var sidex float64 = 4.0
var sidey float64 = 4.0
var pixelLengthx int = 4000
var pixelLengthy int = 4000
var numSteps int = 100

func converges(wg *sync.WaitGroup, i, j int, m *image.RGBA) {
    wht := color.RGBA{255, 50, 128, 255}

    plx := float64(pixelLengthx)
    ply := float64(pixelLengthy)
    fi := float64(i)
    fj := float64(j)

    c := complex((fi-plx/2)/plx*sidex, (fj-ply/2)/ply*sidey)
    zn := complex(0, 0)
    for k := 0; k < numSteps; k++ {
        zn = cmplx.Pow(zn, 2) + c
    }

    if cmplx.Abs(zn) > 0.1 {
        m.Set(i, j, wht)
    }

    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    err := Main()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func Main() error {
    m := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, pixelLengthx, pixelLengthy))
    blk := color.RGBA{0, 0, 0, 255}
    draw.Draw(m, m.Bounds(), &image.Uniform{blk}, image.ZP, draw.Src)

    numGoroutines := pixelLengthx * pixelLengthy
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(numGoroutines)

    for x := 0; x < pixelLengthx; x++ {
        for y := 0; y < pixelLengthy; y++ {
            go converges(wg, x, y, m)
        }
    }

    wg.Wait()

    f, err := os.Create("img.png")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer f.Close()

    err = png.Encode(f, m)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

What is going on here? Why does the program even print something?

I'm using go version go1.8 windows/amd64.

[Memory usage during program execution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOrAu.png)

Comment: It's crashing and trying to print a stack trace. You are trying to start 16 million goroutines at once. Even if that could be efficiently scheduled, do you have the system resources to do that?

Comment: Minimum stack size for `goroutine` is [2KB](https://golang.org/doc/go1.4#runtime), thus 16M requires at least 32GB of memory.

Comment: Is there any technical reason to start 16M goroutines? Or is just to challenge Go how many goroutines are acceptable?

Comment: There is no technical reason to start that many goroutines, just curiosity, and it killed the process. I was afraid of hitting memory restrictions, but the Windows Resource Monitor seems to show that not all of my 16GB of RAM are used, apparently there is some kind of equilibrium between the number of goroutines started and the ones being finished.

Comment: @jonathan: it probably doesn't show the 16GB of ram being used, because it failed to allocate more. If the runtime tries to allocate 32GB and the system only has 16GB, it doesn't return 16GB, it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

goroutine is lightweight but you have too much overconfident. You should make worker like below, I think.

```
package main

import (
    "image"
    "image/color"
    "image/draw"
    "image/png"
    "log"
    "math/cmplx"
    "os"
    "sync"
)

var sidex float64 = 4.0
var sidey float64 = 4.0
var pixelLengthx int = 4000
var pixelLengthy int = 4000
var numSteps int = 100

func main() {
    err := Main()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

type req struct {
    x int
    y int
    m *image.RGBA
}

func converges(wg *sync.WaitGroup, q chan *req) {
    defer wg.Done()

    wht := color.RGBA{255, 50, 128, 255}
    plx := float64(pixelLengthx)
    ply := float64(pixelLengthy)

    for r := range q {

        fi := float64(r.x)
        fj := float64(r.x)

        c := complex((fi-plx/2)/plx*sidex, (fj-ply/2)/ply*sidey)
        zn := complex(0, 0)
        for k := 0; k < numSteps; k++ {
            zn = cmplx.Pow(zn, 2) + c
        }

        if cmplx.Abs(zn) > 0.1 {
            r.m.Set(r.x, r.y, wht)
        }
    }
}

const numWorker = 10

func Main() error {
    q := make(chan *req, numWorker)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(numWorker)
    for i := 0; i < numWorker; i++ {
        go converges(&wg, q)
    }

    m := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, pixelLengthx, pixelLengthy))
    blk := color.RGBA{0, 0, 0, 255}
    draw.Draw(m, m.Bounds(), &image.Uniform{blk}, image.ZP, draw.Src)

    for x := 0; x < pixelLengthx; x++ {
        for y := 0; y < pixelLengthy; y++ {
            q <- &req{x: x, y: y, m: m}
        }
    }
    close(q)

    wg.Wait()

    f, err := os.Create("img.png")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer f.Close()

    err = png.Encode(f, m)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the garbage collector attempting a stop-the-world sweep. The 1.8 GC minimizes but doesn't eliminate STW collection. The actual collection is fast, but first it has to preempt all goroutines before it can finish GC. A goroutine can be preempted by the scheduler when it makes a function call. If you're doing all inline math and tight loops, with many goroutines live, this could take a very long time.

Also, as @JimB and @putu noted, while goroutines are extremely resource-efficient and very large numbers have been used in production circumstances, these circumstances have been with extraordinary resources available (e.g. Google's production infrastructure). Goroutines are light weight, but 16M feathers is still going to be heavy. If your system does not have 32GB+ memory, you're likely over-taxing your machine, not Go itself.

Try running with GOTRACEBACK=crash and GODEBUG=gctrace=1 and see if you can get some probative info from the stack trace when it dies.

A web search for "GC assist wait" turned up this useful thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-dev/PVwDFD7gDuk